# Multicast different values

Tags: java, casting, char, int, byte

Test this segment it's print weird output.But I was think it segment throw exception **possible lossy conversion from byte to char**. but it not throws any exception,can you justify this statements.

> jshell> println((int)(char)(byte)-1);

**output :**
65535

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here - partly because I can't understand the phrase "But I was think it segment throw exception". That code definitely won't throw an exception... could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: char is not hold a negative number.that why i'm think it's throw exception.

Comment: byte b = -1; char ch = (char) b;

Comment: No, those conversions don't throw an exception - just like `(int) Long.MAX_VALUE` doesn't throw an exception. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2